# How to create "image building" effect

Tags: javascript, silverlight, animation

I'm looking for a convinient way to create such an effect in a web application: i have some picture, which has not very high resolution, and i want it to appear as a cloud of particles in some random part of the screen, and then to move to it's position.

It's ok that i will lose some resolution (i don't think that 1x1px particles are nice ;) ).

I want to use silverlight/canvas or processing-js/canvas.

Any ideas?
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your silverlight application loads the picture, what you can do is to split it into tiles. You use one object for each tile and you store the normal position for this tile (i.e. where it is originally in the picture). Then you give each tile a random position, and use a loop to move the tile in a line from the random position to its normal position. This appear as a cloud that resolves into the correct picture.

You can then play around with the size and number of tiles, and how they move to their correct position (you could have them slow down, or follow a curve instead of a straight line).

Comment: Thx, i'm well with math. But there are implementation problem: direct usage of canvas and tiles is too slow...

Comment: Ah. Is there a way to do this without using canvas? Maybe just silverlight by itself? Because it seems fast enough: I was looking at http://w4.clouping.com/Qios.Silvergrid.Website/#/QHomePage$342 and it's nice and smooth.

Comment: This implementation is based on Deepzoom, estimated from image loading... And it's slow too - elements here are more complex, but there are only several tile, while to recreate some picture you need (at least) 300*200 = 60000pix - so you can use SolidColorBrush.
If tiles are bigger, the more complicated brushes are used.